# Test binding of private module

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

In my code there is one third party guice binding that I need to overwrite to work correctly. (Lets name it InterfaceToBeOverridden.class)
To be safe that this is not changed and works correctly, I want to **test** that when asking the injector for a 
InterfaceToBeOverridden instance in fact it **returns an instance of the dummy class**.
The problem is that **this wiring is installed in a private module**.
What's the best way to achieve this using Guice?

The code looks like this:

```
public MainModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // install a lot of prod modules 
        install(new MyChildModule())
    }
}


public MyChildModule extends PrivateModule {
    @Override 
    protected void configure() {
        // install some stuff that also needs parent bindings
        install(Modules.override(new ThirdPartyWiringModule(), new MyDummyOverrideModule()));
        expose(SomeClassUsingThirdPartyDependencies)
    }
}

public MyDummyOverrideModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override 
    protected void configure() {
        bind(InterfaceToBeOverridden.class).to(DummyImplementation.class);
    }
}
```

The core problem here is that I can't access the class from the parent injector because it is in the child scope and 
can not create an injector of the private module itself because it requires bindings from the parent. So both of the 
methods below would fail.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Injector injector = createInjector(new MainModule());
    assertEquals(injector.getInstance(InterfaceToBeOverwritten.class).getClass(), DummyImplementation.class);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    Injector injector = createInjector(new ChildModule());
    assertEquals(injector.getInstance(InterfaceToBeOverwritten.class).getClass(), DummyImplementation.class);
}
```

Comment: Rather than using the `Injector`, you can use `Elements.getElements()` to inspect your `Module`.  You can check the `PrivateElements` for the appropriate binding.